# Yii: Zend's preDispatch and init analogon

Tags: zend-framework, yii

I have to translate an applications from Zend to Yii Framework. Since i'm new to Zend, i wonder how to implement the Controllers preDispatch() and init() functions in Yii. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

For init there is same [`init`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#init-detail)function in Yii controllers.

```
public function init()
{
    // Do some initialization
}
```

For predispatch you can use [`beforeAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail), this will be called just before action - return true if you want action to be executed, or false to cancel execution.

```
protected function beforeAction($action) {          
    // Do some logic just before action
    return true;
}
```

When ovveriding custom controller parent methods should be called.

There is also very usefull [filter for actions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter)